# Confused with multiple basic node.js requests

Tags: node.js, api

Hi I'm trying to combine two api requests onto my simple node.js website. I have them both working separately but I'm struggling to combine both of them to work on the same page.

```
  request(url2, function (err, response, body) {

    if(err){
      res.render('index', {news: null, error: 'Error, please try again',initials111:initials,test:potatoes});
    } else {
      let news = JSON.parse(body);

      if(news== undefined){
        res.render('index', {news: null, error: 'Error, please try again',initials111:initials,test:potatoes});
      } 

      else{
        let newsText = `${news.articles[0].title}`  ;
        res.render('index', {news: newsText, error: null,initials111:initials,test:potatoes});
      }
      }
    }

  );
```

```
  request(url, function (err, response, body) {

    if(err){
      res.render('index', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again',initials111:initials,test:potatoes});
    } else {
      let weather = JSON.parse(body);

      if(weather.main == undefined){
        res.render('index', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again',initials111:initials,test:potatoes});
      } else {
        if (rain == "0,rain"){
        let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees celsius and with wind speeds of ${weather.wind.speed} mph in ${weather.name} ${weather.sys.country}! & ${weather.weather[0].description}`  ;
        res.render('index', {weather: weatherText, error: null,initials111:initials,test:potatoes});
      }
      else{
        let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees celsius and with wind speeds of ${weather.wind.speed} mph in ${weather.name} ${weather.sys.country}!`  ;
        res.render('index', {weather: weatherText, error: null,initials111:initials,test:potatoes});
      }
      }
    }

  });
```

Those are the two sections of code for each request. I can attach screenshots of the website if needed. If I put them both in the server.js file then I get a lot of errors. Can anyone help / give hints ?

For example when I just paste both of them into server.js and try the website I get this error

```
ReferenceError: C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\views\index.ejs:42
    40| 

    41|       

 >> 42|         <% if(news !== null){ %>

    43|             <p><%= news %></p>

    44|           <% } %>

    45| 


news is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:11:8)
    at returnedFn (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at Request._callback (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\server.js:63:13)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\NodeShit\weather-rough\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
```

Comment: Post the errors please.

Comment: 1. "lots of errors" is not helpful in software development 2. without seeing how you combine them into one file, I don't know how we could help you. Please show the code that has problems, not the code that works.

Comment: `if (rain == "0,rain")` - where is rain defined?

Comment: Oh sorry I'll post the errors, I figured there was something behind joining the two requests together as they work perfectly individually. The rain thing is from a checkbox which isn't an issue